# Displaying a FOURCC UYVY video frame in a C# application

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, directshow, directshow.net

I'm getting a byte stream from an encoder device, the byte stream is said to contain a "FOURCC UYVY" image. I need to display that image inside a C# application (Windows Forms), what would be the best way to do that?

I have seen some examples on how it's done using ffmpeg, but it's rather complicated, are there other, more convenient ways to do so?